# Django - Avoid saving unchanged object in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

My admin.py seems to work very well thank you, but my user has the option of clicking "Save" even when nothing has changed. This sets the object's modified_date field which annoys me.

Is there a way to force a cancel when using "Save" in these circumstances to close a change form in the admin? Is it desirable to do so?

Comment: Add a piece of javascript to hide the Save button until an input/select/checkbox is changed.

Comment: I like that one, @pastylegs. It seems to get across the UI idiom I was after.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably write a custom admin form and subclass it for every admin-editable entity where, in the `save()` it looks at all fields which aren't the last_modified_date (I'm assuming you've got this consistently named across your models) and if there are no changes, doesn't call `super(YourAdminFormClassNamehere, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` but if there are changes to any of those fields, it does.

(It's a weekend, else I'd probably add some example code. This should get you on a useful track, though.)

Comment: Thanks. Useful. I see where this is heading.

Comment: :-) Is there an easy way to walk through the fields in a form?

Comment: for (fieldname, field)  in form.fields.items()